# How to add values to checkbox inside a listbox in WP7 Silverlight

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am having problem adding values to the Checkbox.

This is how I want it to work:
When I run the application it should show the "Attendees" name and when I check the box and click "Send" it should retrieve the email address from the attendees i've checked, the email address is attached to the attendee allready, but how can I attach the email to the checkbox value ?

XAML

```
    <ListBox Name="AppointmentResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attendees}" Height="400"  ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" Margin="24,0,0,0" >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="true"      FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                      </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
<Button Content="Skicka" Click="SendPhoto_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

I attach the Appointments to the AppointmentsResultsData datacontext

I hope anyone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a TwoWay binding on the IsChecked property of the CheckBox then you'll be able to iterate over all items in the Attendess collection and see which were checked.

Alternatively you could use the MultiselectList from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550).

Comment: Hi Matt!
Can you please give a sample of the TwoWay binding, XAML and Codebehind-file. Im new to WP7 and Silverlight